# How to draw a triangle?

Tags: .net, vb.net, math, geometry, gdi+

I've inherited the Control class to create a custom user control used to put some shapes, I would like to draw a triangle inside the control counds and I'm drawing an inner border in the triangle but I have messed my head with the pointers, I can't find the right calculation of the points (maths are not my speciality) then instead a triangle I get this ugly figure:

[image]

Below is the relevant part of the code that draws the lines, the problem I think is the fourth `PointF`

> Notes

`p` object is the `Pen` instance that I use to draw the lines.

The `BorderWidth` property of the property grid in the image above is just to set the `p.Width`

> Code

```
Case Figures.Triangle
    Dim trianglePoints As PointF() =
        {
            New PointF(p.Width / 4.0F, CSng(Me.Height) + (p.Width / 2.0F)),
            New PointF(CSng(Me.Width) / 2.0F, p.Width),
            New PointF(CSng(Me.Width) - (p.Width / 4.0F), CSng(Me.Height) + (p.Width / 2.0F)),
            New PointF(-CSng(Me.Height) + p.Width, CSng(Me.Width / 2) - p.Width)
        }

    Using gp As New Drawing2D.GraphicsPath(FillMode.Alternate)

        gp.AddLines(trianglePoints)
        gp.CloseFigure()

        With e.Graphics

            If Not Me._InnerColor = Color.Transparent Then

                Using b As New SolidBrush(Me._InnerColor)
                    .FillPath(b, gp)
                End Using

            End If

            .DrawLines(p, trianglePoints)

        End With

    End Using
```

Comment: To draw triangle usually needs 3 points. Why you have 4?

Comment: No, you need 4 points. Top -> Bottom 1 -> Bottom 2 -> Top. You would only need 3 sets if you are working with individual lines, but if drawing as a path, you need 4 points. However, this is fill path.... Only 3 may be required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last element of the array must be same as first (to close the figure)

```
Dim trianglePoints As PointF() =
    {
        New PointF(p.Width / 2.0F, CSng(Me.Height) - (p.Width / 2.0F)),
        New PointF(CSng(Me.Width) / 2.0F, p.Width / 2F),
        New PointF(CSng(Me.Width) - (p.Width / 2.0F), CSng(Me.Height) - (p.Width / 2.0F)),
        New PointF(p.Width / 2.0F, CSng(Me.Height) - (p.Width / 2.0F))
    }
```

Comment: thanks but does not work as expected, the bottom line is not drawn, maybe it is drawn OUTSIDE the bounds of the control... I don't know, but is not visible

Comment: If `p` is `Pen` why do you use its `Width` in your calculations?

Comment: because as you see in the image above my pen width is not 1, is 20, then is a factor of the calculation... all other lines are good.

Comment: Ok, can you tell or better show, what you want to draw?

Comment: A common Triangle. in this other question you can see an image with the triangle (painted using MSPaint on the image) with the 3 borders visible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26826538/draw-proportional-triangle-inside-control , using your solution the bottom line/border is not drawn inside the bounds

Comment: Thanks but is not fixed, your solution cuts top left and right borders out of the control bounds, here you cna see it: http://i.imgur.com/rIs90Pm.png please note that in the first image that I shown in my question all my triangle borders are visible, I only need to enclose the figure (the bottom line of the triangle).

Comment: Ok, but I think now you have all necessary information to solve your problem.

Comment: You can configure the `Pen` object for better line joining and rounding.

Comment: You can probably overgo including the pen width in your calculation if you select a different `Pen.Alignment` value, e.g. `Inside`.